# where should I insert "else" to reduce "if"

Tags: java, lf

where should I insert "else" to reduce "if"

```
public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=1;i<=12;i++) {
            if(i%6 ==1) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.println("-");
            }
            if(i%6 ==2) {
                System.out.print("+");
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            if(i%6 ==3) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(i);
                System.out.println("#");
            }
            if(i%6 ==4) {
                System.out.print("+");
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            if(i%6 ==5) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(i);
                System.out.println("-");
            }
            if(i%6 ==0) {
                System.out.print("#");
                System.out.println(i);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `switch (i % 6) { ... }` is probably cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Improve with `else`

As all the if are exclusives (only one condition at each iteration can be true), you can put an `else` everywhere. As you do `modulo%6` you can even put a simple `else` for the final one

```
if (i % 6 == 1) {
} else if (i % 6 == 2) {
} else if (i % 6 == 3) {
} else if (i % 6 == 4) {
} else if (i % 6 == 5) {
} else  {
}
```

---

###### Improve with deduplicated blocks

Note that you can duplicated cases, `1,5` and `2,4`, so you can do

```
if (i % 6 == 1 || i % 6 == 5) {
} else if (i % 6 == 2 || i % 6 == 4) {
} else if (i % 6 == 3) {
} else  {
}
```

---

###### Improve with switch and string concatenation

You can also use a `switch` (here the new enhanced switch with blocks that don't require `break` statements), and concatenate the string to get one print call

```
switch (i % 6) {
    case 1, 5 -> System.out.println(" " + i + "-");
    case 2, 4 -> System.out.println("+" + i);
    case 3    -> System.out.println(" " + i + "#");
    default   -> System.out.println("#" + i);
}
```

---

###### Improve with easier code

You can also just store the prefixes and suffixes in arrays and access them

```
String[] prefixes = {" ", "+", " ", "+", " ", "#"};
String[] suffixes = {"-", "", "#", "", "-",  ""};

for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    System.out.println(prefixes[(i - 1) % 6] + i + suffixes[(i - 1) % 6]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For more clearer code, you can use the `switch case` method :

```java
switch (i % 6) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(i);
                    System.out.println("-");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("+");
                    System.out.println(i);
                    break;
.
.
.
```

If you want or need to use if block, youcan use this syntax :

```
            if(i%6 ==4) {
                System.out.print("+");
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            else if(i%6 ==5) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(i);
                System.out.println("-");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("#");
                System.out.println(i);
            }
```